# nested array call back function

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, callback, nested

I have a nested object as below, where array is returned as object using results key.

```
var testList = {
  results: [
    {
      id: 1,
      testList: {
        results: [
          {
            id: 11,
            testList: {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      testList: {}
    }
  ]
};
```

I want a resultset as below, where direct array is returned instead of object of array. Please help!

```
var testList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    testList: [
      {
        id: 11,
        testList: {}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    testList: {}
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var testList = {
results: [
  {
    id: 1,
    testList: {
      results: [
        {
          id: 11,
          testList: {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    testList: {}
  }
 ]
};

console.log("Original:")
console.log("var testList =",JSON.stringify(testList, null, 2))


let tempList = []
if(testList.results){
  for(let i = 0; i < testList.results.length; i++){
    let r = testList.results[i]
    let newEntry = {
      id: r.id,
      testList: []
    }
    if(r.testList.results){
      for(let j = 0; j < r.testList.results.length; j++){
        newEntry.testList.push(r.testList.results[j])
      }
    } else {
      newEntry.testList = {}
    }
    tempList.push(newEntry)
   }
 testList = tempList;
}
console.log("Modified:")
console.log("var testList =",JSON.stringify(testList, null, 2))
```

or if the testList if going to be infinite nested levels deep you can do it recursively like this:

```
function flattenResults(list){
  let newList = []
  if(list.results){
    for(let i = 0; i < list.results.length; i++){
      let r = list.results[i]
      let newEntry = {
        id: r.id,
        testList: []
      }
      if(r.testList.results){
        newEntry.testList = flattenResults(r.testList) //recursive call
      } else {
        newEntry.testList = {}
      }
      newList.push(newEntry)
     }
   }
 return newList 
}

testList = flattenResults(testList)
```

Comment: Yes, it is infinte nested levels deep. I tried the recursive one and it works perfectly. Thank you for the help.